# booststrap popover left position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a popover that shows the comments that have been made in a certain information shown on a website.
This is the code I have, that creates the popover.

```
        var popoverOptions = {
            placement: element.position().left > 550 ? "left" : "right",
            trigger: "hover",
            html: 'true'
        };

        element.removeClass('icon-white');
        element.attr('title', $.i18n._('msg_comment'));
        element.attr('data-content', comment.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
        element.popover(popoverOptions);
        element.tooltip('destroy');
```

This is my HTML

```
<span class="icon-comment budgetCommentAction" data-id="date=2014-09-01&amp;countryCode=AR&amp;gameId=12&amp;channelId=2" data-content="2014-10-10 11:00:02 msalamanca: test 2
<br />
<br />2014-10-06 16:54:09 msalamanca: Test" data-original-title="Comment" title="">
</span>
```

The thing is that when the popover appears, it appears over the element I am hovering on.

[image]

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Could you please share some fiddle. It's hard to say smth when you see just some part of code.

Comment: Why not "top auto" so it shows above or below based on the space. Also, don't you have an option for the container?

Comment: I didn't know that I can do "top auto". I'll try that.